# How to find out why json_encode is failing (PHP)?

Tags: php, json

I have huge csv with a list of names and dates. I need to put a subset of these into a PHP struct for a given month. So I run through the CSV and filter those rows where the months is what I desired submit the names to a list and then save that list to a file using json_encode.

I do this once for every month for a total of 12 times as I just need one year.

I did months 1 through 7 with NO issue. Now month 8 fails. The list is generated but nothing is stored because the json_encode fails.

Calling on json_last_error_msg() provides the message Malformed UTF-8 characters.

I read the CSV by doing

```
  if (($handle = fopen($in_csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {           
           $line++;
           
           $data = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);  // <- This was added after the first failure. But I have tried without it

           // ... do stuff with data and save the name and last name to a struct. 
           
       }       
       fclose($handle);
   }

   // At the end I do
   $fid = fopen("filename","w");
   fwrite($fid,json_encode($output));
   echo "JSON ENCODE RESULT: " . json_last_error_msg() . "\n";
   fclose($fid);
```

I really need this to work. Is thre ANY way that JSON can tell me what it doesn't like so I can delete it or correct it?

Comment: Do you get any error? As per [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) you can tell PHP to `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` by passing options as the second argument and then find out why the encode is failing.

Comment: A wild guess here would be you would need to do [`mb_convert_encoding`] (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

you can try doing something `mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')`;
This is usually the case for Cyrillic languages

Comment: We can't replicate the problem since we don't know anything. Always include errors and what the variables hold when it does not work.

Comment: @JimWright Yes the reason why is failing is the one in the question "Malformed UTF-8 characters." However I don't know which ones are supposed to be Malformed, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Andreas The error is in the question, as I've said the variable is composed of text string of over 500 names. How should I provide the variable contents?

Comment: @JimWright, This will at least let me generate the output: JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE. So thank you for pointing me to that page!!!

Comment: Had the same problem. array_map() command solved it.  I found out which data caused it by print the output to the screen.  With my eye technology,  I saw  a char with a diamond shape.  I am with you on this. If JSON_encode() can point at which data is at fault, this would save me hours and don't need to rely on my eye technology.

Comment: @aarefovich  Did 'JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE' argument specify which data is at fault?

Comment: @Nguaial Sorry, this iswas avery old problem and I do not remember trying what you are suggesting. Regars

Answer (score 2):

This error usually occurs due to the incorrect encoding of the data in this case (UTF-8 encoding).Check for all the syntax in the data especially check for commas `,` as you have a CSV file.

As per the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) the `json_last_error_msg()` throws this type of error.

**JSON_ERROR_UTF8:** Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

If you have a problem finding a error manually in the large csv file.You can use one of these libraries.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-validator

https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-file-validator

Comment: I know, this is the error, but I don't know where it is. This subset of o rows from the CSV is about 1000 lines and I can't just manually search the 1000 lines for the 1 that has an error. It's why I'm trying get something that might indicate which is the malformed character

Comment: I'll checki it out If I run out of options. I don't have installed nor have I ever used npm. Thank you for your suggestion though. You have been most kind

Comment: Glad to help you @aarelovich and if this helps you please do remember accept this as an answer

Comment: Doesn't seem to be somthing usefull in my case as it will validate fields given what I wan't them to be and not based on incorrect encoding

Comment: Hmm Ok @aarelovich